# Does $\log z$ have a laurent series about $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I think not because $\log z$ isn't analytic on any neighborhood of 0. Is this correct? thanks

Comment: How would you *define* $\log(z)$ in a neighborhood of $0$?

Comment: @MartinR That's the question. The reason I'm asking is because in my exam today i was asked to classify the singularity at $0$ of Log z.  I claimed since it wasn't analytic on any neighborhood of 0 (i.e. any open ball centered at $0$), it didn't have a Laurent (or a Taylor) series at 0. So it doesn't have a pole or a removable singularity there.  But it has a branch point at $0$.

Comment: @Loli: that is very close to the answer I would give.

Comment: There is no n such that z^n * ln(z) gives a nonzero constant as z approaches 0. So there’s no way to really describe its pole and get a Laurent series for it around z=0

Comment: Tiny nit. Some functions fail to be analytic on any neighborhood of $0$ but are defined and analytic on a punctured disc around $0$ and yet do not have a pole or a removable singularity or a branch point. $e^{1/z}$ is a standard example. People call that kind of singularity an "essential" singularity. What differentiates it from the $\log$ / branch point type case is that with an essential singularity, you at least can actually define an analytic thing in a punctured neighborhood of the point, with $\log$ you can't.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Tristan Needham's approach found in his book "Visual Complex Analysis" to define the formal Laurent series of the complex logarithm as
$$\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}, \ c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_0 \frac{\log(z)}{z^n}\frac{dz}{z}$$
and the formula would read
$$\log(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} c_n x^n.$$

Whether this contour integral works or not for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ seems to be solved nowadays, regarthless it exists for $n=-1$. We would need to find these explicit values $c_n.$

Nevertheless, everyone says there does not exists a Laurent series expansion for logarithm, for example:

> Now what about log(z)? That one has singular points called "logarithmic branch points" of infinite order since circuits around the origin or infinity around the function never return to the starting value. These too are not poles since they also are not issolated and so therefore do not have Laurent series expansions about their singular points.

Source https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/log-z-singularity-series-and-pole.601750/